# Serialize object to XML, no namespace, can read Interface property

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I already tried many resolutions from googled results.

Initially my working code is using XmlWriter and XmlSerializer, with custom features to suppress namespace, and remove nil attribute.

Working great, till attempt to do over Entity object with navigation property as interface.
XmlSerializer bomded out when a property is interface.

Then tried the DataContractSerializer, it can run over the Interface property, but now with namespace coming back, as using DataContractSerializer.WriteObject, there is no entry for passing in XmlSerializerNamespaces as like the XmlSerializer.

The object is not a DataContract.

Found an sample to remove namespace using DataContractSerializer, but it's using custom XmlTextWriter, but I'm having problem to pass in XmlWriterSettings, which is supported by XmlWriter.Create(x.x)

What I need is a simple serializer to chunk out xml from an object:

- without namespace
- can work/read with Interface property

Comment: Could you please refine your requrements. Would be great to provide a mockup of your object you would like get serialized

Comment: Entity object generated by Entity Framework 6.0, a property generated is a ICollection<something>, Interface break XmlSerializer